# How do I solve for the phase constant given the amplitude and the angular frequency?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

> A piston (with mass M) in a car engine is in vertical simple harmonic
>   motion with amplitude A. The engine is running at a period T.  Suppose
>   a small piece of metal with mass m were to break loose from the
>   surface of the piston when it (the piston) is at the lowest point z
>   and velocity is v.
>   At what position in meters does the piece of metal lose contact with the piston?

Also the maximum velocity and acceleration are given.

The text book gives these equations:

$x(t) = Acos(wt+φ)$

$v(t) = -wAsin(wt+φ)$

$a(t) = -w^2Acos(wt+φ)$

So I propose that the best way to figure this out would be to solve for the time at which acceleration is at its max, then plug that time into $x(t)$.  But I must first solve for the phase constant.  Is this correct?  If so, how do I find the phase constant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phase constant is needed only if you have a specific initial condition, e.g. if I told you where $x$ was at time $t = 0$, you could solve for $\varphi$. Otherwise you can just choose whatever you want for it: Note that it is the same in all functions.

Choosing some value for $\varphi$ is analogous to you manually setting the time origin to something you like. Imagine observing the harmonic motion for a while, and then deciding that $t = 0$ should be the time where the piston is all the way up. Or you could decide that $t = 0$ should be the time where the piston is all the way down. Or right in the middle.

Thus, for your problem, you can just set $\varphi = 0$.

Comment: That is just what I wanted to hear.  I would send you cookies.